# Style dd and dt tags with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I created dt and dd tags in my javaScript. I also have some styling for them in my CSS file. But I am switching to bootstrap, how can I style them?

```js
const pre_tx = document.createElement("pre");
const dt_tx = document.createElement("dt");
const dd_tx = document.createElement("dd");
```

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 110px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

dt::after {
  content: ":";
}

dd {
  margin: 0 0 0 60px;
  padding: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML: This is the DIV that displays the dt and dd data: -->
<div class="displays" id="display"></div>
```

How can I get the same styling with bootstrap?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of what you are trying to achive. The code provided does not help understand what you'd like to do

Comment: Do you have `<dt>` and `<dd>` in a `<div>`? I believe it would be best to include HTML (not just a `<div>`) as a [mcve] as blurfus requested.

Comment: using Bootstrap on top of applying your own styling is perfectly fine